# How to loop a a macro in excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to loop a certain macro in excel VBA. However, I don't know how to do this (I tried and failed multiple times). The annotations in the code below are given to show what I want to do. The code as it is works perfectly, I just want it to loop for every chunck of data until all data has been transposed into the second worksheet (the first worksheet contains about 5000 rows of data, and every 18 rows has to be transposed into 1 row in the second worksheet):

```
    Sub test()

' test Macro

Range("G2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]/RC[-1]*100"
Range("G2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("G2:G19"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("G2:G19").Select
Range("A2:C2").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2_Transposed data").Select
Range("A2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
    'I want to loop this for every next row until all data has been pasted (so A3, A4, etc.)
Sheets("Sheet1_session_data").Select
Range("G2:G19").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2_Transposed_data").Select
Range("D2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=True
Range("D2:U2").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
    'Here I also want to loop for every next row until all data has been transposed and pasted (e.g. D3:U3, D4:U4 etc.)
Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
Sheets("Sheet1_session_data").Select
Rows("2:19").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ' Here I delete the entire data chunck that has been transposed, so the next chunck of data is the same selection. 

End Sub
```

Hope this question was understandable, and I hope someone can help.
Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean you want to loop? there are other data in `Sheet1_session_data`? Cause in your code, you already deleted the entire `Row("2:19")`. or does that mean after you have looped through all the columns? Can you somehow show sample data, and expected result? We can help post screen shots, just provide the link.

Comment: Edited post, I need to tranpose 5000 (or more) rows of data, and every 18 rows is data from 1 user that has to be transposed into 1 row on the second worksheet.

Comment: ah i get it. But, i leave it to @Siddharth Rout. :D

Comment: Can you give me a sample data so that I can give you an exact code with explanation?

Comment: See comment under your answer. Thanks a lot for helping!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can actually reduce your code.

**First Tip:**

Please avoid the use of `.Select/.Activate` [INTERESTING READ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

**Second Tip:**

Instead of doing an Autofill, you can enter the formula in the relevant cells in one go. For example. this

```
Range("G2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]/RC[-1]*100"
Range("G2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("G2:G19"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

can be written as

```
Range("G2:G19").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]/RC[-1]*100"
```

**Third Tip:**

You don't need to do a copy and paste in separate lines. You can do it in one line. For example

```
Range("A2:C2").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2_Transposed data").Select
Range("A2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

can be written as

```
Range("A2:C2").Copy Sheets("Sheet2_Transposed data").Range("A2")
```

Same thing when you are doing a PasteSpecial. But you use `.Value = .Value` soo this

```
Range("G2:G19").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet1_Transposed_data").Select
Range("D2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=True
```

can be written as

```
Sheets("Sheet1_Transposed_data").Range("D2:D19").Value = _
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G2:G19").Value
```

Missed the `Transpose` part. (Thanks Simoco). In this case, you can write the code as

```
Range("A2:C2").Copy 
Sheets("Sheet2_Transposed data").Range("D2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
```

**Fourth Tip:**

To loop through cells, you can use a `For Loop`. Say you want to loop though cells `A2` to `A20` then you can do like this

```
For i = 2 To 20
    With Range("A" & i)
        '
        '~~> Do Something
        '
    End With
Next i
```

**EDIT:**

Your before and after Screenshots (**From Comments**):

[image]

and

[image]

After seeing your screenshots, I guess this is what you are trying? **This is untested as I just quickly wrote it.** Let me know if you get any errors :)

```
Sub test()
    Dim wsInPut As Worksheet, wsOutput As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, NewRw As Long, i As Long

    '~~> Set your sheets here
    Set wsInPut = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1_session_data")
    Set wsOutput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2_Transposed data")

    '~~> Start row in "Sheet2_Transposed data"
    NewRw = 2

    With wsInPut
        '~~> Find Last Row
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Calculate the average in one go
        .Range("G2:G" & lRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]/RC[-1]*100"

        '~~> Loop through the rows
        For i = 2 To lRow Step 18
            wsOutput.Range("A" & NewRw).Value = .Range("A" & i).Value
            wsOutput.Range("B" & NewRw).Value = .Range("B" & i).Value
            wsOutput.Range("C" & NewRw).Value = .Range("C" & i).Value

            .Range("G" & i & ":G" & (i + 17)).Copy

            wsOutput.Range("D" & NewRw).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

            NewRw = NewRw + 1
        Next i

        wsOutput.Range("D2:U" & (NewRw - 1)).NumberFormat = "0"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I understand my code can be shorter, thanks for that. But I do need to loop (see edit question)

Comment: That I also understand, thank you. But I don't want a set selection range. I want to be able to loop until all data from the first worksheet has been transposed into the second. (Because the amount of data will differ from time to time, sometimes 5000 rows of data, sometimes 15000 rows of data).

Comment: @ArcoJansen: Have you seen [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)? simply replace `20` with `LastRow`

Comment: @ArcoJansen: I still think, you may not need a loop. See the `EDIT` in my updated answer. Let me know if that is what you are trying to do?

Comment: Hi, @SiddharthRout:) Good explanation:) but as I see OP wants to transpose data: `Selection.PasteSpecial ... Transpose:=True`. Maybe you need to change last code in third tip?) Or I've missed something?

Comment: @SiddharthRout i think `A2:C2` gives identity to the user. `G2:G19` is percentage of that particular user. So every `18-row` is another user which needs to be transpose and consolidated to the other worksheet. i'm sloppy in imagination as well, but that's how i read the OP's code. Since you're at it, i leave it you :p hahaha

Comment: @simoco: incorporated. thanks. Dunno how I missed that.

Comment: @L42: Asked for sample data. See last line of the answer. Lets see what happens now.

Comment: I think you should also change the same thing in "Edit" part:)

Comment: @simoco: Yeah I thought about that but then decided to wait for the sample data because I have a feeling that I will have to change that part after I see the data :)

Comment: Alright, here is the link to sample data (First and second worksheet). Links: 1. http://imageshack.com/a/img834/6505/i5nu.jpg 2. http://imageshack.com/a/img811/2600/y232.jpg

Comment: @ArcoJansen: I understood sheet1 but not sheet2. What are those values? scrore or max score?

Comment: Ah I am sorry. That's what I also do in my code, I make an extra column containing the percentage of the score (so: score/maxscore*100). What's in the second sheet under the "variables" are the percentage scores (which I make as an extra column in the first sheet).

Comment: @ArcoJansen: So shouldn't the values in Col M to U be below D to L?

Comment: @ArcoJansen: Can you shown me an exact output of sheet 1 in sheet2?

Comment: @SiddharthRout: I don't think I understand what you are asking me.

Comment: @ArcoJansen: See my last comment. simply create two rows with the exact output in sheet2 and provide me the link and I will take it form there.

Comment: @SiddharthRout: I will show the output after I run the current code once: 1. http://imageshack.com/a/img713/861/zafh.jpg 2 .http://imageshack.com/a/img856/7456/ltjo.jpg

Comment: @ArcoJansen: Ok I got it :)

Comment: @ArcoJansen: I still think one of the image is wrong because 2/21 is not 33 it is 9.22. :) unless it is 7/21

Comment: @ArcoJansen: One last question. Is the data always sorted and there are 18 entries per user?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yes, you are correct haha, that should be 7/21 ;). Yes, there are always 18 entries per user and it is always sorted the exact same way.

Comment: @ArcoJansen: See my updated post (EDIT Section) You may have to refresh the page.

Comment: @SiddharthRout: It works like a charm, exactly what I wanted! Thanks a lot, you really helped me out! I understand what you did, and will apply it to future macro's. Amazing :).

Comment: @ArcoJansen Glad it all worked out in the end... And yes... Don't forget the tips :p